# Search engine for website

Tags: javascript, search-engines

Does anybody have any recommendations for a search engine that I can use for my website. I currently use Google CSE, but am wondering if there is anything better.

I want to be able to have the search results display certain data such as an image, header, information, etc...

I would prefer something that I have some familiarity with such as javascript but I'm open to all suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SearchBlox is another option to check out. There is a comparison between Google Mini and SearchBlox http://www.searchblox.com/comparison-of-searchblox-vs-google-mini

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to use JavaScript,( I know that you mentioned that because CSE uses it, but it would be ineffective in retriving from a database really,) you would have to use PHP or ASP.NET etc. Unless you are good at these, i would advise not to do it as you need to create a crawler aswell, which is pretty advanced. 
If you are still on, there are many youtube videos and online tutorials that may help you, it would also have been easier if you had been a bit clearer about your abilities and your targets and aims

regards,
Niall

Answer (score 0):

Bing has an XML site search api.  It allows you to search what is already indexed by bing, including images.  The results are either in JSON or XML.

if you want to get more detailed than that, and actually want to search based upon headers, meta tags, etc, then its time to build your own spider to crawl and index your pages and throw them in a db which can be searched.